# Best way to design database rails polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Two models:

Patient & Symptom

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

and

```
class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base  
end
```

I saved all the application default symptom in symptoms table.

```
Default symptoms: fever, headache
```

Also, I want to save individual patient symptom in the same table,

```
Patient symptom: cough
```

I can't use the polymorphic, since the default symptoms has no model.( taken from yml file)

Answer (score 0):

A patient has many symptoms and a symptom belongs to a patient.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :symptoms
end

class Symptom < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

So this requires a patient_id of type integer in the symptoms table to work

You obviously have your own requirement for a set of default symptoms but I would question that as it doesn't make much business logic sense having a default set of symptoms, however that is what you have so you need a method to load the default symptoms from your yml file in your patient class.

That answers your specific question but I am not sure you have asked the right question and you need to sort out your business logic. I would guess that you would need a diagnosis that has a set of symptoms that would act as the join table as a many to many relationship between patient and symptoms.